# FailoverClusters module is not getting listed while running the cmdlet Get-Module -ListAvailable

Tags: powershell, failovercluster

I tried below command

```
    Get-Module -ListAvailable
```

But it did not showed me "FailoverClusters" in the list

From where I can download this module? Do I have to install any SDK? 
Note: I do not want to install Azure SDK. Is there any other way?

**Update**
I am using my local windows 10 to remote connect to the Azure Virtual Machine (Windows Server 2012 R2). I do want to manage all configurations using powershell from my local windows 10 machine.

Comment: Download and install the appropriate version of the Remote Server Administration Tools, then enable the "Failover Cluster Management" feature

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [jisaak already explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36333440/712649), the `FailoverClusters` module is installed when you install the Failover Clustering feature on a Windows Server.

If, however, you want to manage a cluster from a computer *without* the Failover Clustering feature installed, this is what you do:

1. Download the appropriate version of [Remote Server Administration Tools](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2693643)
2. Run the installer
3. Navigate to the Programs and Features control panel pane (run `appwiz.cpl`)
4. Choose "Turn Windows Features on or off"
5. Find the "Failover Cluster Management" feature under Remote Server Administration Tools
6. Enable it

Voila

Answer (score 1):

> The FailoverClusters Windows PowerShell module is installed on the
>   computer with the **Failover Clustering feature**

[Source](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461009.aspx)

[Install the Failover Clustering Feature](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770506.aspx)

Comment: RSAT contains the module as well, no need to add the Failover Clustering feature

Comment: what you mean by RSAT ? Remote Server Admin Tool?

Comment: He is right. With RSAT he means Remote Server Administration Tools.

Comment: I want to use remote desktop from my local system. I can not add fail over clustering feature in local machine. so from your comment i sense that we have to use powershell inside virtual machine

Comment: @codetoshare No, RSAT works on non-server versions of Windows as well